# same mysql queries are much slower when running from script

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql script with many queries operating (creating, joining, inserting,etc.) on tables of sizes of several million rows. I run the script on Linux (server version 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, InnoDB engine) using

```
mysql -ppassword -uuser db < script.sql
```

Using `show processlist;` I find that some queries in the script are really slow - they are stuck in `Sending data` state and take an hour or more to complete. When they complete similar queries in the same script take less than 2 minutes.

Confusingly, if I run the same script pasting commands line by line directly into the mysql console, all queries, even the first one, take less than 2 minutes. Also, I can kill the long running query from the script and rerun it interactively in the same 2 minutes.

It cannot be an effect of caching because I am testing two different fresh instances.

What could be causing such a difference?

Comment: Nothing obvious.  Let's see some slow queries.  There may be tips to make them faster.